# Python turning CSV to JSON with headers

Tags: python, json, csv

I'm trying to create a JSON from a CSV using python. This issue I'm running into is a method of separating headers from data. My current code is:

```
import csv
import json

with open('input.csv') as f:
    columns = ("Column 1", "Column 2")
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, columns)
    rows = list(reader)
with open('output.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(rows, f, indent=4)
```

but this returns

```
[
{
    "Column 2": null, 
    "Column 1": "Title"
}, 
{
    "Column 2": " data2", 
    "Column 1": "data1"
}, 
{
    "Column 2": " data4", 
    "Column 1": "data3"
}, 
{
    "Column 2": " data6", 
    "Column 1": "data5"
}
```

]

instead of

```
[
    "Title1": {
        {
            "Column 2": " data2", 
            "Column 1": "data1"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data4", 
            "Column 1": "data3"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data6", 
            "Column 1": "data5"
        }
    }
]
```

Heres an example of what the CSV would look like for reference:

```
Title
data1, data2
data3, data4
data5, data6
Title2
data1, data2
data3, data4
data5, data6
```

Comment: You'll need to explicitly build another data structure. A dict-reader may not help you here.

Comment: You example is not quite possible. You `"Tittle1"` as the key of a dict with no keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than just using `list`, you need to build up the nested data structure yourself. Here's one way you could do it:

```
import csv
import json

with open('input.csv') as f:
    columns = ("Column 1", "Column 2")
    reader = csv.DictReader(f, columns)
    tree = {}
    for row in reader:
        if row["Column 2"] is None:
            current = []
            tree[row["Column 1"]] = current
        else:
            current.append(row)
```

When a "title" row is found (one where the second column is empty), a new list is added to the tree. Further rows are added to this list, until another "title" row appears, and a new list is started.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for the most part. I had to convert tree to a string then replace all single quotes with double ones, in order to conform to JSON syntax. I then wrote it to a json file to get the output I wanted.

Comment: Why not just use `json.dump` as you were?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that part was obvious so I didn't include it!

Comment: No it was I just wasn't thinking when I implemented the write to file

Answer (score 0):

You need to message your data as read to a different structure.

Something like:

```
data={}
with open('/tmp/f.csv') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for sl in (row for row in reader):
        if len(sl)==1:
            key=sl[0]
            data[key]=[]
        else:
            data[key].append({"Column {}".format(i):e for i, e in enumerate(sl,1)}) 

>>> json.dumps(data, f, indent=4)   
{
    "Title2": [
        {
            "Column 2": " data2", 
            "Column 1": "data1"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data4", 
            "Column 1": "data3"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data6", 
            "Column 1": "data5"
        }
    ], 
    "Title": [
        {
            "Column 2": " data2", 
            "Column 1": "data1"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data4", 
            "Column 1": "data3"
        }, 
        {
            "Column 2": " data6", 
            "Column 1": "data5"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something like this?

```
titles = ['Title', 'Title2']
output = {}
for line in f:
    if line[0] in titles:
        title = line[0]
        output[title] = {}
        output[title]["Column 1"] = []
        output[title]["Column 2"] = []
    else:
        output[title]["Column 1"].append(line[0])
        output[title]["Column 2"].append(line[1])
```

Returns:

```
{   'Title': {   'Column 1': ['data1', 'data3', 'data5'],
                 'Column 2': ['data2', 'data4', 'data6']},
    'Title2': {   'Column 1': ['data1', 'data3', 'data5'],
                  'Column 2': ['data2', 'data4', 'data6']}}
```